# editing google doc programmatically

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf, google-docs

I need simple search-replace in doc file exported from google doc. and than upload it to google doc.

How do I do it in python ?

google doc also support pdf export. If editing pdf is easier , I will try that instead of doc.

I am using google app engine envrionment with python.

I am able to download and upload file easily. Just can't figure out how to edit the file programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Google Data API's will only allow you to export and upload documents. To manipulate the document itself, it will probably be easiest to export to OpenDocument format (.odt), and use a Python library for that. Search the Python Package Index for "opendocument" and you will find some. [ezodf](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezodf) and [lpod](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lpod-python) seem not too difficult at first sight.

Comment: superb thanks.....(( cursing myself... why i didn't think beyond word & pdf ? :) ))

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Google Data APIs Python Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/).

For example, you can write to a spreadsheet (for example) easily. "Matt Cuts" has a ticket on his blog about that : http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/write-google-spreadsheet-from-python