# Is there a way to modify google document with python script?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I am using python and writing a script to create a google document with PyDrive, upload it to google drive and modify the document as well. I am following the instructions from pydrive documentation (https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/).

So far, I am able to create a document, upload/download and set permissions. I am looking for other capabilities from pydrive like modifying the document, adding paragraph, set font or insert table from the python script. I see all this in python-docx (https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Do we have this in google drive api using pydrive as well?

Comment: If there's no direct way that you can find, a workaround could be to download the document in some format like .docx, then use a library that can edit that document format, do the editing with that library, and then upload it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [editing google doc programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482925/editing-google-doc-programmatically)

Comment: Are you already able to connect to google drive? via oauth or something else? Maybe show us some of your code.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect, for example, how about using the method of documents.batchUpdate in Google Docs API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) In this case, you can use googleapis for python. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)

Comment: @CryptoFool I will try that. Will have to check how effectively I can edit the document. I may need to use rich features similar to Microsoft word. So, will give it a try thanks.

Comment: @Tanaike  do you mean updating the document using json style format? Never tried that. Will check the link, thanks.

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes that was my next plan  :) To use python-docx for editing.

Comment: Also, found this link which is very helpful. https://mdeore.medium.com/automated-documents-google-docs-api-97df5602660e

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this using google doc APIs as suggested. Reference to this is [developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents)
[Google doc API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents)